# Volume of the solid using cylindrical shell method

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

The region $R$ is bounded by the $x$-axis, the vertical lines $x = \frac 12$ and $x = a$ for some $a > 1$; and the graph of $y = \frac 1\pi(e^{x^2-x})$. Find, in
terms of $a$, the volume of the solid obtained by rotating $R$ about
the line $x = \frac 12$
by $2\pi$ radian.

Hi everyone, how do i solve this question using cylindrical shell method? May I kindly get the workings ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: With shells, you integrate *radially out from* the axis, i.e. a height function of $x$ with respect to $x$, having multiplied by $x$ (so useful in this case). With disks/washers, you integrate *along* the axis, i.e. a radius function of $y$ with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\tau = 2\pi$ and $e(x) = e^x$. The radius from the axis of rotation ($x = 1/2$) is $r$ and the height of the cylinder is $y$. The volume of the solid is given by

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{a - 1/2} \tau r y \, dr &=
\int_{1/2}^{a} \tau(x - 1/2) \frac{e(x^2 - x)}{\tau/2} \, dx \\ &=
\int_{1/2}^a (2x - 1) e(x^2 - x) \, dx.
\end{align*}
Consider $u = x^2 - x$. Then, $du = (2x - 1) dx$. The endpoints $x = 1/2$ and $x = a$ are substituted by $u = -1/4$ and $u = a^2 - a$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_{1/2}^a (2x - 1) e(x^2 - x) \, dx &=
\int_{-1/4}^{a^2 - a} e(u) \, du \\ &=
e(u) \bigg\vert_{u = -1/4}^{u = a^2 - a} \\ &=
e(a^2 - a) - e(-1/4) \\ &:=
e^{a^2 - a} - e^{-1/4} \\ &=
e^{a(a - 1)} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{e}}.
\end{align*}
Let me know if this was helpful.